# jquery validation multiple error label locations

Tags: jquery, validation, location, label

Using jquery validation, is there a way to have each error message displayed in a different location.

I want to display the "required" message next to the email field, but the "invalid email address" in a validation summary div at the bottom of the form.

I know i can use errorPlacement but I think this is for all messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `errorPlacement` method in `.validate()` to contain the error placement logic. 2 arguements are passed to `errorPlacement`:

1. **error**: the error text to be inserted into the DOM.
2. **element**: the element being validated.

You can use the error message returned by the validator to decide where it should be positioned. EG:

```
$("form").validate({
  ignore: '',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element){
    if(error.text() == "This field is required"){
      $('.requiredContainer').text(error.text());
    }
    else
    {
      $('.genericContainer').text(error.text());
    }
  });
});
```

If you're using this with multiple forms, I would suggest putting all of your validator settings in `setDefaults()` and just using `validate()` to handle rules/messages etc

[setDefaults docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults)